# Improper integration limits

Tags: improper-integrals

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ such that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx = c$. Also, $f$ is even.

Is the following equation correct?

$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx -\int\limits_{b}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

Comment: Correct! In fact, $$ \int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx =\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx +\int\limits_{b}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

Comment: If $f \ge 0$ it is certainly true. Not sure in general

Comment: @F.G if you assume $\int_b^\infty f$ exists. Can we guarantee this?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=c$ can implies this.

Comment: Moreover, I think it's correct even if $\int_b^{\infty}f=\infty$ since $\int_a^{\infty}f$ will also be $\infty$ in this case.